# Subclass B Inherits From a Template Class A<B>

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, metaprogramming

I recently stumbled upon code that looks like this and I can't wrap my head around it:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
}

class B: A<B>
{
}
```

---

So my general questions are:

- **Why does this not give a compile error?** Specifically how can class `B` inherit from the template class `A<B>`, if `B` hasn't even been defined yet?
- **When would this structure ever be necessary?**

Comment: C++ doesn't use a one-pass compiler.  Referring to things that have been defined further down in the code is perfectly legal.

Comment: This is known as the "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks! Looks like some interesting reading material!

Comment: _"Why does this not give a compile error?"_ A template argument is not required to be a complete type, unless the template uses the argument in a way which would require it to be a complete type at the point of instantiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the features: this template pattern can help you to avoid `vtable` usage. This called "Static polymorphism" - http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Suppose you have this code structure:

```
class Item {
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
}

class A : public Item {
// …
}

class B : public Item {
// …
}

Item *item = new A();
item->func();
```

It can be replaced with this:

```
template<typename T>
class Item {
public:
    void func() {
        T::func();
    }
}

class A : public Item<A> {
// …
}

class B : public Item<B> {
// …
}

Item<A> *item = new A();
item->func();
```

This way you can avoid virtual function call. This can be done for some performance improvement...

Comment: But why would you need a virtual call at all now that `A` objects cant be grouped with `B` objects by casting them as `Item` pointers?

Comment: @Calpratt this can be helpful if class composition hierarchy is fixed in compile time. I think grouping is unavailable in this situation.

Comment: @Calpratt this concrete example is better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26718782/440168